# How to get the latitude and longitude in Open layers

Tags: reactjs, openlayers, latitude-longitude, openlayers-3

I am drawing one line from Location A to Location B using React.JS with Open Layers. I wish to get the Latitude and Longitude of the Location A and Location B.

I have added one listener after draw completion. But it is giving the co-ordinates as below . How can I get the latitude and longitude?

**Listener:**

```
     draw.on('drawend',function(e){
        console.log("Co Ordinates :",e.feature.getGeometry())
        //console.log("Co Ordinates :",e.feature.getGeometry().getExtent())
        });
```

**Console :**

Extent and flat coordinates values are printed in console as below

```
extent_:(4) [8732987.679175382, 1920132.5190330548, 8735555.9637923, 1920254.817578509]
flatCoordinates:(4) [8732987.679175382, 1920132.5190330548, 8735555.9637923, 1920254.817578509]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking for a way to convert the coordinates you can use [`ol.proj.transform(coordinate, source, destination)`](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.proj.html#.transform)

Using this

```
ol.proj.transform([8732987.679175382, 1920132.5190330548], 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326')
```

Will give this as output

```
[78.44976308230713, 16.99405070970775]
```

Also note that you can use [`getFirstCoordinate`](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.geom.LineString.html#getFirstCoordinate) and [`getLastCoordinate`](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.geom.LineString.html#getLastCoordinate) methods on the line feature to get the first and last coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

OpenLayer is working on different location formats like EPSG: 3857, EPSG: 4285 etc.
There are some Transform/Projection api [enter link description here](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.1/apidoc/ol.proj.html#transform)

Use this api's and transfer your locations to your desired formats